# Getting result close to certain number

Tags: mysql, sql

Following is my sqlfiddle in which I am trying to display result against the given name and as per its feature number (`the number against the given name`) my query should generate results and show all those names and feature number that are close to it.
For example (from following table) the user searches for `jhon` and its feature number is `20` then my query should show result for numbers that are close to 20 like 18,19,21,22 I want to set the closing limit to 2. Like for number 20 the close limit is 18,19,21,22.

Kindly let me know how can I do it.
Thanks,

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c177a/1

```
+--------------------+
| NAME    |  Feature |
+--------------------+
| Jhon    |    20    |
| Jame    |    18    |
| Jimm    |    21    |
| Kim     |    30    |
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    searching a
        INNER JOIN searching b
            ON a.feature BETWEEN b.feature - 2 AND b.feature + 2
WHERE   b.name = 'gore'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c177a/2)